# Fundamental Group of $\mathbb{RP}^n$ not using Van Kampen

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am trying to calculate the fundamental group of $\mathbb{RP}^n$ without using the Van Kampen Theorem. My basic idea consists of the following: First of all, $\mathbb{RP}^1\simeq S^1$ and thus, the fundamental group for $n=1$ is just $\mathbb {Z}$.

For $n\geq 2$ I have thought of the following covering map: $ p:S^n\to S^n/_{x\sim-x}\simeq \mathbb{RP}^n,\ x\mapsto [x]$. This is obviously continuous and surjective. Furthermore, $S^n\simeq \mathbb{RP}^n\times \{x,-x\}$. Thus, this map should be a covering.

Now we look at the function $\phi: \pi_1(\mathbb{RP^n},x_0)\to p^{-1}(x_0)=\{x_0,-x_0\},\ [w]\mapsto L(w,x_0)(1)$ where $w$ is a loop in $\mathbb{RP}^n$ and $L$ is the lift of $w$. Now, it is known that $\phi$ is well-defined and bijective. Now we know that $p^{-1}(x_0)\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$. Thus, in order to prove that the fundamental group of $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is indeed $\mathbb{Z}_2$, we need to show that $\phi$ is a group homomorphism. This is where I am struggling at. Could someone help me?

Comment: There is a unique group of order $2$.  You don't need it to be a homomorphism.

Comment: "Furthermore, $S^n\simeq \mathbb{RP}^n\times \{x,-x\}$." This is false; $S^n$ is a double covering of $\mathbb{RP}^n$, but is not a disconnected double covering (because $S^n$ is connected).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese but when you look at the map $f:x\mapsto ([x],x)$, you get, that it is surjective (you get $([x],-x)$ through $f(-x)$) and trivially injective. Furthermore, it should be continuous due to $\mathbb{RP}^n\simeq S^n/_{x\sim -x}$ (thus, through the quotient topology). Is perhaps the inverse not continuous? What covering would you otherwise suggest?

Comment: The codomain of a map can't depend on a point in the domain. For $n = 2$, what would $(1, 0, 0)$ map to? What would $(0, 1, 0)$ map to?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Why wouldn't $(1,0,0)\mapsto ([1,0,0],(1,0,0))$? and $(0,1,0)\mapsto ([0,1,0],(0,1,0)$?

Comment: You're defining a map to $\mathbb{RP}^n\times S^n$ which is not what I think you are intending to do. Regardless, it's not a homeomorphism.

Comment: Ok. So the covering map is wrong. Which one could I use?

Comment: The covering map is $p : S^n \to \mathbb{RP}^n$, $x \mapsto [x]$.

Comment: Isn't that what I used? The part with $S^n\simeq \mathbb{RP}^n\times \{x_0,-x_0\}$ was just the verification that it indeed is a covering. However, you have disproved that. So how can it still be a covering map?

Comment: The condition to be a covering map is a local one; it need not be the case that $S^n \simeq \mathbb{R}P^n \times \{x_0, -x_0\}$ in order for the mentioned $p$ to be a covering map. Of course, that is not the case anyway, since if such an equivalence held, taking fundamental groups would imply that $0 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: The projection $S^n\to RP^n$ is easily seen to be a covering map, nobody disproved this and nobody is going to disprove this. What other commenters noted  is that your statement "Furthermore, $S^n\cong RP^n\times \{-x,x\}$. Thus, this map should be a covering." are just nonsense: The first one is simply nonsense and the second one (while true) does not follow from the nonsensical first statement.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Could we maybe avoid words that may unnecessarily demotivate learners, such as "nonsense" and their derivatives? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will proof that $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n) \tilde{=} \mathbb{Z}$ for $n = 1$ and $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n) \tilde{=} \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$ for $n \geq 2$:
To establish the assertion for $n=1$, we show that $S^1 / \sim$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$. Thereby, we think of $S^1$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\psi : S^1 \to S^1$ be the map $\psi(z) := z^2$. Clearly, $\psi$ is continuous and surjective. We have
\begin{equation}
z \sim w \iff \psi(z) = \psi(w).
\end{equation}
Thus there is a bijection $\tilde{\psi} : S^1/\sim \to S^1$, such that $\psi = \tilde{\psi} \circ p_1$. Since $S^1 / \sim$ is endowed with the final topology, $\tilde{\psi}$ is continuous. Since $S^1 / \sim$ is compact and $S^1$ is Hausdorff, $\tilde{\psi}$ is a homeomorphism.
To treat the case $n \geq 2$ we are going to analyse the fundamental group $\pi_1(S^n/ \sim)$ using a covering given by the space $S^n$ and covering projection $p_n$. We get this covering the following way:
For $n \geq 2$ we define $\sim \subseteq S^n \times S^n$ be the equivalence relation
\begin{equation}
x \sim y :\iff (x=y \lor x = -y)
\end{equation}
and let $p_n : S^n \to S^n / \sim$ be the canonical projection. Let $S^n / \sim$ be endowed with the final topology $\mathcal{V}$ induced by $\lbrace p_n \rbrace$. Then $(S^n , \mathcal{T}_n, p_n)$ is a covering of $(S^n/\sim, \mathcal{V})$.

To start with, let us fix notation. Set $x_0 := (1,0, \ldots, 0) / \sim \in S^n / \sim$, which will be used as base point and set $\tilde{x_0} := (1,0, \ldots, 0)$. For a loop $f \in L(S^n / \sim, x_0)$ denote by $\tilde{f}$ the lifting of $f$ with initial point $\tilde{x_0}$.
Now we use that the covering $p_n : S^n \to S^n / \sim$ is 2-fold. For every loop $f \in L(S^n / \sim, x_0)$ the terminal point of a lifting $\tilde{f}$ belongs to the two-element set $\lbrace \tilde{x_0}, - \tilde{x_0}\rbrace$. Now we use that $S^n$ is simply connected. If $f,g \in L(S^n / \sim, x_0)$ with $\tilde{f}(1)= \tilde{g}(1)$, then $\tilde{f} \sim \tilde{g}$ and hence $f \sim g$. We conclude that $\pi_1(S^n/ \sim)$ has at most two elements.
Let $1_{x_0}$ be the constant path at $x_0$. Its lifting $\tilde{1_{x_0}}$ clearly is the constant path at $\tilde{x_0}$. If $f$ is a loop with $f \sim 1_{x_0}$, then by the following theorem:

> **Theorem** (*Monodromy theorem*): Let $\langle \tilde{X},\tilde{\mathcal{T}},p\rangle$ be a covering of $\langle X, \mathcal{T} \rangle$, $x_0,x_1 \in X$, and let $f,g : [a,b] \to X$ be two FEP-homotopic paths in $X$ which both have initial point $x_0$ and terminal point $x_1$. Let $\tilde{x_0}$ be in the fiber of $x_0$ and let $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$ be the liftings of $f$ and $g$, respectively, with initial point $\tilde{x_0}$. Then $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$ have the same terminal point and are FEP-homotopic.

we have $\tilde{f}(1) =\tilde{x_0}$. In order to show that $\pi_1(S^n/\sim) \neq \lbrace 1 \rbrace$, it is thus sufficient to find one loop $f$ with $\tilde{f}(1) \neq \tilde{x_0}$.
Consider the path $\tilde{f} : [0,1] \to S^n$ given as $\tilde{f}(t) := (\cos(\pi t), \sin(\pi t), 0, \ldots, 0)$ for $t \in [0,1]$. Then $\tilde{f}(0) = \tilde{x_0}$ and $\tilde{f}(1) = - \tilde{x_0}$. Pushing $\tilde{f}$ to $S^n / \sim$ gives a loop with base point $x_0$: $f(t) := (p_n \circ \tilde{f})(t) = (\cos(\pi t), \sin(\pi t), 0, \ldots, 0)/ \sim$ for $t \in [0,1]$.
By definition $\tilde{f}$ is the lifting of $f$.
To conclude the proof, note that up to ismorphism there is only one group with two elements, namely $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: what is the monodromy theorem?